# xUnit only reporting results for single file

Tags: jenkins, xunit

I have added a post-build action called `Publish xUnit test result report`, I have then added a JUnit sub-section and specified the paths to my xml files. I know that xUnit is finding all of the specified files (`[xUnit] [INFO] - [JUnit] - 3 test report file(s) were found with the pattern`) however xUnit proceeds to base the success of the build on only one of the files and `Latest Build Results` also shows the breakdown of the tests from the same single file.

xUnit at no point logs an error or exception or indicates that it has had any sort of issue with any of the files when specified individually or all together.

If I set up a separate build for each file, xUnit correctly calculates the build success and reports the results for all of the files.

When I specify multiple files only the first file is used.

How do I get xUnit to report the results for multiple files in a single build?

I have tried:

- Appending all test results into a single file.

  - This leads to the XML being badly formed and unparseable.
- Adding multiple JUnit sub-sections (one for each file).

  - This is no different to normal, only the first specified file is used to report success and display results.
- Upgrading xUnit to the latest version, from **1.96** to **1.101**.

  - No change.
- Enabling the xUnit logger for more information.

  - The logger contains no more useful information, only `[xUnit] - [JUnit] - 3 test report file(s) were found with the pattern '*_test_output.xml' relative to...`

Example output of one of the test results files:

```
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="all tests" errors="0" failures="2" tests="176468" hostname="tbd" time="1.79972" timestamp="tbd">
    <testcase classname="Test Section" name="Test Name" time="0.000091"/>
    <testcase classname="Test Section" name="Test Name" time="0.000221">
      <failure message="2 &lt;= 1" type="REQUIRE"> 
          at path/path/path path/path/path/file.cpp:106
      </failure>
    </testcase>
    <system-out/>
    <system-err/>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Comment: FWIW, I don't see this behavior with xUnit v 1.99. What version are you using? It could be something in the test result content that xUnit is having trouble parsing. Can you compare the file content? I see you reported [JENKINS-33248](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33248), but you'll probably need to provide more information for the developers to reproduce.

Comment: @DaveBacher The content of each file is individually parse-able and reportable, it seems to be the combination, however they're all completely bog-standard, no frills JUnit XML test reports...

Comment: @DaveBacher What extra information should I include? There aren't any other settings that would seem to have any effect, what would I need to supply?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the problem with the information provided. It's possible that it has something to do with your JUnit report content. If you can provide a minimal example of the failing reports that might help. Also, perhaps there are more hints in the xUnit log output, see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin#xUnitPlugin-Showingthedetails%3A

Comment: Another option is to try the plain [JUnit publisher](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin).

Comment: @DaveBacher Thank you for the help, I'll enable the logger. The plain JUnit publisher has less control over the number of failing tests and the pass/fail state of the project...

Comment: @DaveBacher I enabled the logger, nothing helpful in there... updating the question to provide more information!